# Xcode 14.3 file not found issues preventing code from running successfully

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode14, xcode14.3

after updating to Xcode 14.3, my code is not running anymore, some of the errors attached in the screenshot below, any suggestion please?
[image]

I tried installing pods and updating them, cleaning the project and rebuilding, adding missing files, and many other.. but nothing worked

Comment: If any of your pod has minimum deployment target 8.0 or under 8.0, then change it to 11.0..But not sure on it.

Comment: Did you open the project instead of the workspace? When using Cocoapods you need to open the workspace.

Comment: I tried @SupriyoDey solution, but didn't work too

Comment: @HangarRash I have Cocoapods so I am opening the workspace not project

Comment: Which version of cocoa pods are you using?  You might need to update cocoapods to account for Xcode 14.3 changes.

Comment: @valosip i have cocoapods 1.12.1